# pdfviewer: Cannot read property 'FontInspector' of undefined?

Tags: angular, pdf-viewer

to view the pdf i use the module ng2-pdf-viewer I use this line of code

```html
<pdf-viewer *ngIf="pub.PieceJointesPublications[0]&&pub.PieceJointesPublications[0].type=='Pdf'" [src]="BasicUrl +pub.PieceJointesPublications[0].path" [original-size]="false" [zoom]="0.5" [show-all]="false" [render-text]="true" style="display: block; position: relative;"></pdf-viewer>
```

any one have an idea how to fix this error:
core.js:1449 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'FontInspector' of undefined